# MissingSubscriptionRegistration: The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

Tried to run the [CreateVMExample.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/compute/CreateVMExample.java) from Azure-Java-SDK

```
   VirtualMachine vm = ComputeHelper.createVM(
                        resourceManagementClient, computeManagementClient, networkResourceProviderClient, storageManagementClient,
                        context, "javaSampleVM", "Foo12", "BaR@123rgababaab")
                        .getVirtualMachine();

                System.out.println(vm.getName() + " is created");
```

and got the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: MissingSubscriptionRegistration: The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.storage.StorageAccountOperationsImpl.create(StorageAccountOperationsImpl.java:737)
    at com.microsoft.azure.utility.StorageHelper.createStorageAccount(StorageHelper.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.azure.utility.StorageHelper.createStorageAccount(StorageHelper.java:53)
    at com.microsoft.azure.utility.ComputeHelper.createVM(ComputeHelper.java:246)
    at com.microsoft.azure.utility.ComputeHelper.createVM(ComputeHelper.java:213)
    at com.microsoft.azure.auth.CreateVMExample.main(CreateVMExample.java:74)
```

As I'm new to Azure from AWS, couldn't understand where to begin. saw same kind of error releavnt to Azure PS. But not much helpful. Please suggest something. I'm using Azure Active Directory Auth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by authenticating with Azure AD.
The doc "Authenticating Azure Resource Management request"( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx) says "All of the tasks that you do on resources using the Azure Resource Manager must be authenticated with Azure Active Directory. ". So using the Azure Resource Management API of Class `ComputeHelper` must be authenticated with AAD.

You need to setup authentication on Azure AD by using the Management Portal firstly. For the steps of details, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx#bk_portal and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/.

There is a sample project (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-graphapi-web) for calling Azure AD in Java that it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the storage account name that you are referencing is an old storage account? If you go to portal.azure.com storage accounts will be listed in two categories: storage accounts (classic) and storage accounts. If the account you are referencing is in the classic list, try creating a new storage account and then reference that?

Comment: Thanks fo rthe reply, Jason. now I'm getting java.io.EOFException:as follows.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
 at com.microsoft.azure.management.storage.StorageAccountOperationsImpl.create(StorageAccountOperationsImpl.java:737)

any Idea what to do done for this?

Comment: Did you try out the steps that Peter Pan mentioned? Do they help?